# Set server_default value for relationship table

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables for administrators and roles, connected vía the third table `assignments` (many-to-many relationship) with the fields `role_id`, `administrator_id` and some extra fields `created_at` and `updated_at`, which I would like to populate automatically:

```
assignments = db.Table('assignments',
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')),
    db.Column('administrator_id', db.Integer,
              db.ForeignKey('administrators.id')),
    db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now()),
    db.Column('updated_at', db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(),
              onupdate=db.func.now()),
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(['administrator_id'], ['administrators.id']),
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(['role_id'], ['roles.id'])
)

class Administrator(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'administrators'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('administrators_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True, server_default=text("''::character varying"))
    name = Column(String(255))
    surname = Column(String(255))

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=assignments,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('roles_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    name = Column(String(255))
```

But when I assign a role to an administrator

```
admin.roles = [role1]
db.session.add(admin)
db.session.commit()
```

it breaks with the following error:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1265, 19, 3, null, null).
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO assignments (role_id, administrator_id) VALUES (%(role_id)s, %(administrator_id)s)'] [parameters: {'administrator_id': 19, 'role_id': 3}]
```

Is there any way to set a default value for `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in `assignments` table?

Comment: This works fine for me. You need to make sure that your database actually has a default on those columns, and not just specified on `server_default` in Python.

Comment: @univerio It works for me for other models (without specifying the default value in the database), but when a table row gets created via many-to-many relationship relationship, it just ignores `server_default`

Comment: That's what a `server_default` is. It's nothing more than syntax for specifying that you want a `DEFAULT` clause in the database when you create the table. It has no effect after that. It sounds like you either specified `default` on those other columns or you already had a `DEFAULT` on those columns in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked using `default` and `onupdate` parameters instead of `server_default` and `server_onupdate`:

```
db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime, default=db.func.now()),
db.Column('updated_at', db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(),
          onupdate=db.func.now()),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime, server_default=text("now()"))
```

Comment: It still ignores `server_default` value